# Generate import statement programmatically using typescript compiler API

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to generate the following import statement:

```
import { Something } from 'a-module';
```

To do so I am using [typescript compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API):

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
    `source.ts`,
    ``,
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
    false,
    ts.ScriptKind.TS
);

const printer = ts.createPrinter({ newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed });

const importNode = ts.createImportDeclaration(
    /* decorators */ undefined,
    /* modifiers */ undefined,
    ts.createImportClause(
        ts.createIdentifier('Something'),
        /* namedBindings */ undefined
    ),
    ts.createLiteral('a-module')
);

const result = printer.printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, importNode, sourceFile);

console.log(result);
// prints --> import Something from "a-module";
```

How can I add the curly braces syntax to the import statement? Could be something related to `namedBindings` parameter in `createImportClause` but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found it (as I guessed one must use `namedBindings`):

```
// [...]

const importNode = ts.createImportDeclaration(
    /* decorators */ undefined,
    /* modifiers */ undefined,
    ts.createImportClause(
        undefined,
        ts.createNamedImports(
            [
                ts.createImportSpecifier(undefined, ts.createIdentifier('Something')),
            ]
        )
    ),
    ts.createLiteral('a-module')
);

// [...]
```

Comment: random fyi: you'll end up with `import { Something as  } from "a-module"` at least with current typescript and ttsc.

`ts.createImportSpecifier(undefined, ts.createIdentifier('Something'), ts.createIdentifier('Something'))`
gets
`import { Something as Something } from "a-module"`
which is close to desired effect

Comment: Oh, because of a newish `isTypeOnly` param. I'll throw on an answer below to have better formatting than is available in comments

Answer (score 0):

slightly updated version of @revy's answer in case anyone finds this

```
const { factory } = ts; // or context
const importNode = factory.createImportDeclaration(
    /* modifiers */ undefined,
    factory.createImportClause(
        /* isTypeOnly */ false,
        /* name (default import) */ undefined,
        factory.createNamedImports([
            /* isTypeOnly */ false,
            /* propertyName, inclusion would lead to 'Something as ' */ undefined,
            factory.createImportSpecifier(undefined, ts.createIdentifier('Something')),
        ])
    ),
    factory.createLiteral('a-module')
);
```

results in

```
import { Something } from "a-module";
```

and note that to get a file path import, you'll want `createStringLiteral` e.g.

```
factory.createStringLiteral('some/file/path')
```

becomes

```
import { Something } from "some/file/path";
```